# Using UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, nstextcontainer

I am trying to create a textview that holds a 3 line string. As the user works, the string will update and become wider, the height (number of lines) will remain the same. Reading through the documentation I understand that the size of the container cannot change, it is readonly.

I have code that places text into the text property of a UITextView but it will not scroll the text right or left. I played around with inserting a UIView into the textview and believe that will work, but doesn’t seem like the way to about this. I’m kind of figuring that I need a custom UITextView class and a custom NSTextContainer. Wondering if the proper direction? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: I’d like to be able to interactively add text to the textview and have its width be able to expand. The textview needs to be able to scroll as the text will at times be wider than the view itself.

Comment: When the text's width becomes wider than the view, should it become expanded OR scrollable? (you can't have both!)

Comment: And do you have any line breaks in the text? Since without line breaks, and you want to wrap it to 3 lines, and you want the text view to be scrollable, there's no way to tell *where* to break the line.

Comment: Khanh, I’d like the text to become scrollable. I have three lines with line breaks. Essentially, the first line is a header line with the data in the next two lines. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Since they seem to be separate, how about using 3 UILabels inside a view, and make the view scrollable if the UILabels' size change? You can use [UILabel sizeToFit] and [UILabel sizeThatFits] to findout the width of the UILabels, and to position them properly. However if you're creating an app, it's usually better to let the text wrap the screen's width, so that the user doesn't have to scroll horizontally (in the worst case, only vertical scrolling is required -- vertical scrolling is much more natural than horizontal).

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, Khanh. The piece I'm building would be similar to the score board for a baseball game with the inning number as the top row, the visiting team for the second row, and the home team for the third row. In that scenario you could have the lines wrap. However, I have considered the idea about resizing the labels to fit. My thinking was it would just appear more consistent to keep the font the same size and allow the user to scroll across if desired.